# Stuck with Low Resolution on Newer Kernels

Tags: debian, nvidia, resolution

I have a system running Debian Sid with a Nvidia graphics card. On updating my kernal past `5.15.0-2` my resolution is locked to 1024x786. I've tried `5.15.0-3`, `5.16.0-2`, and `5.16.0-3` and they all have the same problem.

My Nvidia driver version is `470.103.01-2` which is the latest as far as I can tell.

Any advice on how to fix? I'm not even sure where to start looking to be honest. I can see that Nvidia has a later driver (`510.54`) on their website, do I just need to wait for that to be available in Sid?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: 510.54-1 is available in [experimental](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianExperimental): https://packages.debian.org/experimental/nvidia-driver

Comment: @A.B so you think its just a driver issue and I need to wait for the updated drivers?

Comment: I don't think anything. Personally,  I avoid Nvidia because of the kind of issue this brings. But as you were suggesting to wait for the newer version of the driver to appear in sid, I wrote you don't have to wait, it's available in experimental. As your current state is quite broken, you don't have much to lose by trying experimental.

Comment: @A.B ah OK. Ya understood Nvidia isn't ideal but its what I have at the moment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Updating the drivers solved my problem.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Other people with this problem would benefit by knowing which version of which driver fixes it.